# TypeError: obj is not a constructor (error in js / node)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Note: I'm normally coding in Python, so I am completely new to javascript.

I'm trying to use the following repo: https://github.com/omerdn1/otter.ai-api

I used the setup code, but I replaced the import with the following instead: `const OtterApi = require('otter.ai-api')` because I was getting `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

However, now I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: OtterApi is not a constructor`. If I look at index.js in the repo, it does look like a constructor? First part of the code is:

```
class OtterApi {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    this.options = options;
    this.user = {};
    this.csrfToken = '';
  }

  init = async () => {
    await this.#login();
  };
```

The code I'm trying to run:

```
const OtterApi = require('otter.ai-api');

const otterApi = new OtterApi({
    email: 'email', // Your otter.ai email
    password: 'pw', // Your otter.ai password
});

async function main() {
    await otterApi.init() // Performs login
}

main();
```

I get the error when using `new OtterApi()`. I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: How do you export `OtterApi`? Very likely you need to import it as `const { OtterApi } = require('otter.ai-api');`

Comment: @VLAZ Unfortunately, that is also what I tried, but I'm getting the same error either way. I also tried adding `"type": "module"` to package.json, but it led to the same error (with the suggested import method in the readme).

Comment: You still haven't said how you export the class.

Comment: That's in index.js in that repo. I believe they do it like this: `export default OtterApi;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the "default" export:

```js
const OtterApi = require('otter.ai-api').default;
```